# htaccess RewriteRule for www / https not working if both conditions present

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm running into a problem with .htaccess rewrite rules and wondered if anyone could help.

I have a set up which redirects any non-www. url to www. however I also need to introduce an https redirect. After looking for a while I found the first example below, however, its causing a redirect loop error in all browsers.

The 2nd example works fine for all scenarios except for a visit to www.example.com which doesn't direct to https. Does anyone know of a way around this at all?

```
# Redirect Loop
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [R,L] 

# Works (without ssl redirect)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I've tried the following conditions which all result in the same error

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
```

**Full htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,NE]

    # Removes index.php from URLS
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all traffice through the site index
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **single rule** to add `www` and `https`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to replace both of your rules with this rule and clear your browser cache.

Comment: Hi anubhava, thank you for adding the response. This appears to technically be working as the URL redirects to https://www.example.com however the page displays the same 'TOO MANY REDIRECTS' error. I've added the full .htaccess to the question to see if there is a problem elsewhere.

Comment: Did you completely clear browser cache. Other than I see no problem with this rule as this is tested and working rule. `%{HTTPS}` doesn't work on some servers if you're behind some proxy. I need to be offline for 2 hours then I will check further.

Comment: Cache was completely cleared, I also checked on multiple browsers. I'm starting to believe it is a hosting related issue rather than code as I tried this locally and it worked just fine. The only time it didn't redirect was if someone tried accessing the site via https example . com which didn't redirect to https www . example . com

Comment: If this rule is very first rule in site root .htaccess then `https://example.com`  will also become `https://www.example.com`